# How can I do a count in Linq with many to many

Tags: linq, many-to-many

So I have

```
Business
Jobs (many per business)
JobApplications (many per job)
```

I just want to count the total number of Applications for a business.

But I dont seem to be able to go

Business.Jobs.JobApplications

if I use

Business.Jobs.SelectMany(l => l.JobApplications

is accessible from there but I dont understand how to connect and count.

Comment: `Business.Jobs.SelectMany(l => l.JobApplications).Count()` ?

Comment: Does each `JobApplication` has exactly one `Job` and one `Business`? If so, this is not "many to many".

Comment: @leppie thats the correct answer if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Is this LINQ using the Entity Framework (or similar)? Because if it is, leppie's code might load all `Jobs` and all `JobApplications` from the database to memory, which might be slow. Can you add some details? Maybe give some code to show what you have, and what the ourput should be (one `Business business`? all of them?)

Comment: @DaleFraser: You can give it to Matthew North

Comment: @Kobi: Fixed it for him :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Business.Jobs.SelectMany(c => c.JobApplications).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to replace a bit the names.

```
bussiness
    .Select 
    (b => new 
        {
            id = b.id, 
            applications = b.jobs
                .Select (j => j.jobapplications.Count ()).Sum ()
        }
    )
```

The above has worked for the following structure:

```
void Main()
{
    var bussiness = new List<Bussiness>()
    {
        new Bussiness
        {
            id = 1,
            jobs = new List<Jobs>()
            {
                new Jobs
                {
                    jobapplications = new List<JobApplications>()
                    {
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications()
                    }
                },
                new Jobs
                {
                    jobapplications = new List<JobApplications>()
                    {
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications()
                    }
                },
                new Jobs
                {
                    jobapplications = new List<JobApplications>()
                    {
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications()
                    }
                }

            }
        },
        new Bussiness
        {
            id = 2,
            jobs = new List<Jobs>()
            {
                new Jobs
                {
                    jobapplications = new List<JobApplications>()
                    {
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications()
                    }
                },
                new Jobs
                {
                    jobapplications = new List<JobApplications>()
                    {
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications()
                    }
                },
                new Jobs
                {
                    jobapplications = new List<JobApplications>()
                    {
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications(),
                        new JobApplications()
                    }
                }

            }
        }   
    };

    //bussiness.Dump();

    bussiness.Select (b => new {id = b.id, applications = b.jobs.Select (j => j.jobapplications.Count ()).Sum ()})
    .Dump();
}
public class Bussiness
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Jobs> jobs {get;set;}
}
public class Jobs
{
    public IEnumerable<JobApplications> jobapplications {get;set;}
}
public class JobApplications
{

}
```

You would need to apply it on your structure.